# Filter for nested data structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I would like to display all data on my page by default. But if the user adds some keywords into the search field, then I would like to filter the displayed data by their uiUnits IDs.

The data structure, Dashboard:

```
[
    {
        "id": "interface A",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "abc"
            },
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "xyz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "interface B",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "zzz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

component.html

```
<input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
<button (click)="filterUnits(searchTerm)"></button>
<div *ngFor="item of dashboard">
    <div *ngFor="unit of item.uiUnits">
        <p>{{ unit.id }}</p>
        <p>{{ unit.type }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
dashboard: Dashboard;

filterUnits(data: string) {
    this.dashboard.filter((x) =>
        x.uiUnits.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    return this.dashboard;
}
```

The filterUnits function does not work, could someone please help me how to fix it?

Comment: `uiUnits` is an `array` so you cant access the property `id`, you need to iterate over its elements.

Answer (score 0):

As @akotech mentioned in the comment, you need to iterate with `uiUnits` array for filtering the `id`.

And you have to assign the filtered result back to `this.dashboard` so its value is reflected.

```js
filterUnits(data: string) {
  this.dashboard = this.dashboard.filter(
    (x) =>
      x.uiUnits.find(
        (y) => y.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) > -1
    )
  );
}
```

With the above filtering logic, by filtering with "abc", the item (`interface A`) which has the `uiUnits` with `id: abc` will be displayed.

> abc
>
> widget
>
> xyz
>
> widget

---

**Additional**

In case you need to return the `uiUnits`' element with only match the `id` with `searchTerm`, you can use the filtering logic below:

1. Filter `uiUnits` array by search term.
2. With `Array.map()` to produce a new array, when `uiUnits` is not null nor empty array, create a new object and append `uiUnits` to the object. Otherwise, return `null`.

```js
this.dashboard = this.dashboard.map((x) => {
  let uiUnits = x.uiUnits.filter(
    (y) => y.id.toLowerCase() == data.toLowerCase()
  );

  return uiUnits
    ? {
        ...x,
        uiUnits: [...uiUnits],
      }
    : null;
});
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bu37py?file=src/app/app.component.ts)